# Is it possible to pass an optional argument in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to run shell script for two datasets. I am passing dataset name as parameter.

But one dataset has the parameter `exec_seq` and the other doesn't, but the script is the same for both the datasets. Is there any way to pass an optional argument?

Example:

We have two datasets:

```
AMPIL
MDM
```

We are running the script using the command below:

```
bash script.sh AMPIL
bash script.sh MDM
```

But now I have to pass one more parameter, `exec_seq`. This parameter is applicable only for AMPIL dataset not for MDM. How can we check if no parameter is passed, meaning it should run for MDM, and if any parameter is passed then it should run for AMPIL?

```
bash script.sh AMPIL exec_seq
bash script.sh MDM
```

Comment: I think the word you want is not "temporary" but "optional". And really, this question could be reduced to "how do I check if a variable in bash is empty?", which should already exist in the knowledge base.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If the first parameter is `AMPIL`, is the second parameter always going to be `exec_seq`? And if yes, why does it even have to be passed – can't the script look at the first parameter and then behave accordingly? Can you add a minimal version of `script.sh` that demonstrates the desired behaviour?

Comment: Your question is vague. Do you still need to pass the dataset name, if `exec_seq` means AMPIL and no `exec_seq` means MDM?

Answer (score 1):

Example: Make parameter 5 optional.

You can process an optional parameter i.e. `$5` by fetching its contents by, for instance,

```
${5:-cockroach}
```

If parameter 5 is **absent or empty**, its value is assumed to be *cockroach*.

If the user wants to explicitly specify parameter 4 and 6, and leave parameter 5 as the default, he passes the empty string as 5th parameter.